# Static variable is not participated in serialization then how its value is available for the manipulation

Tags: java

Questions by a recent interviewer:

1. Can a static variable participate in serialization process? If no, then how its value will be available for use?
2. Can a static method be transient?

Comment: Please don't destroy improvements to your post, I have rolled back your edit.

Answer (score 1):

> 1.)I came to know the question by interviewer is ,can static variable can be participate in serialization process.

No, unless you override the special serialization methods.

> if no then how its value will be available for use.

Why not? It's still a variable. The question doesn't make sense.

> 2.)can static method be transient.

**No** method can be transient. Again the question doesn't make sense.

Either the interviewer wants to see whether you're an idiot, or he is.

Comment: I guess Interviewer was checking my presence of mind even in the wrong question.